# Call ruby function through AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I barely know anything about ajax, and I need to use it for my rails application. My function is here (controller function):

```
def verify_code
  input = params[:input]
  code = params[:code]
  if input == code
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

The javascript that I have attempted:

```
$('#submit_me').click(function() {
  var input_code = $('.input_code').val();
  var bool = $.ajax({
        url: '/verify_code/'+input_code+'/<%= @code %>',
        type: 'get',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     });
  alert(bool)
});
```

I have idea how to get this ajax going. I am trying to call the controller function and getting the return value to the javascript. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there! You need to implement the "done" callback (= Javascript function that will be executed on the success of the Ajax request):

Try this:

```
$('#submit_me').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var input_code = $('.input_code').val();
  $.getJSON('verify_code/'+input_code+'/<%= @code %>').done(function(data){
    alert(data);
  })
});
```

- jQuery's getJSON method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm still having a problem, I'm getting a routing error.

Comment: I need more info to help you... Also, a routing error means the request didnt match an existing route. Can you post the relevant part of your routes.rb and the error's stack trace?

Comment: the route in routes.rb:
    `get '/verify_code/:input_code/:code', :to=>"patients#verify_code", :as =>'verify_code'`

error in the terminal:
    `Started GET "/patients/[object%20Object]" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-15 16:04:42 -0400
Processing by PatientsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"[object Object]"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms

ActionController::RoutingError (Not Found):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9:in 'render_404'`

Comment: Oh, I see, you need to take off the first '/' of the url in the getJSON

Comment: Ok I'm now getting an error saying that there is no template. Is there supposed to be a respond_to json format?

Comment: you can finish your `verify_action` with a `render :json => @my_object.to_json` where the `my_object` is the variable containing what you want to send back to the client

Comment: Oh and also you need to stop the submit event of the form because it will try to redirect you. I added `event.preventDefault();` and the event argument to the click callback in order to stop the regular behavior of the form.